# C++ #include not working

Tags: c++, header, include

I'm trying to include a function like this in C++ and I can't understand why it's not working. I have 3 files.

**test.cc**

```
int test() {
  std::cout << "This is a test" << std::endl;
}
```

**test.h**

```
int test();
```

**main.cc**

```
#include "test.h"

int main() {

    test();
    return 0;
}
```

This is the error I got and the command I used.

```
c++ main.cc -o main
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "test()", referenced from:
      _main in main-12ba52.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: What is the error that you're getting? Post it please. I suspect this is a linker problem, not a compiler problem.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Nothing wrong with the include, as long as `test.cc` is listed for compilation, howover it wont compile. `std::cout` is not declared. You must `#include <iostream>` in `test.cc`.

Comment: test.cc is missing some #includes

Comment: @Ranic I added the error and command to my question.

Comment: `c++ main.cc -o main` only compiles `main.cc`. You also need to compile `test.cc` into `test.o`, then link `test.o` and `main.o` together into an executable.

Comment: This error is telling you that even though you declared `test()`, it was not defined. It happened because `test.cc` was not included in your project for compilation.

Comment: Can anyone give me an example makefile for compiling two files together? I tried to make one myself but I kept getting the same linker error.

Comment: c++ main.cc test.cc -o main

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the culprit.

> c++ main.cc -o main

You need to link test.o.

> c++ main.cc test.cc -o main

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using your compiler properly, try to include `"test.h"` on the top of your `test.cc` file:

```
#include "test.h"

int test() {
   std::cout << "This is a test" << std::endl;
}
```

Compile with:

```
g++ main.cc test.cc -o main
```

Answer (score 2):

You should add the following to `test.cc`:

```
#include "test.h"
#include <iostream>
```

And make sure you're building/linking with `test.cc`

Comment: I tried that and it still gave me the linker error.

Comment: Just edited to say that you need to make sure you're linking against it.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of function test has undefined behaviour because it does not return a value though it has return type int

```
int test() {
  std::cout << "This is a test" << std::endl;
}
```

As you did not report what is the error I think that the problem is that you did not include in the project file test.cc. You have to link it along with file main.cc that the linker would be able to find the definition of test.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I hadn't actually realised that my function was wrong. The problem is that I'm getting a linker error.

Comment: @Francis  You have to link the both modules together that the linker would be able to find the definition of test.